# Is there an integral type you can use that holds any enum value

Tags: c++

I have some code where I need to do `static_cast<foo>(bar)` where `foo` is an integral type (say, simply, `int`) and `bar` is an enumeration value.

Is there a type that I can use for `foo` that *guarantees* that the `static_cast` is valid for *any* enumeration value for *any* enumerator?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853368/underlying-type-of-a-c-enum-in-c0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853368/underlying-type-of-a-c-enum-in-c0x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing set out specific to enumerations in `<cstdint>`, but given that enumerations have to be integral types you could use

`intmax_t`

if your enumeration has negative values, or

`uintmax_t`

if there are no negative values.

These two types are defined as the widest integral types on your system. It's a pity you need to treat the unsigned and signed cases separately. There is no type that will work for all possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's `std::underlying_type_t<decltype(bar)>`.

If you need a common type for all enums, there's `union { intmax_t s; uintmax_t u;}`. Obviously, which of the two members to use in which case depends on the signed-ness of each individual enum type:

```
template<typename E> 
std::enable_if<std::is_signed<std::underlying_type_t<E>>::value, 
  intmax_t>::type foo( // ...
```

Comment: Plus one, this is interesting for the future but, of course, doesn't address the common type for *any* enumerator.

Answer (score 1):

No, since there might be some enumeration types `x` and `y` where the underlying type of `x` is `long long` and that of `y` is `unsigned long long`.

There's no type in the standard that could fit all `signed` *and* `unsigned` `long long` values.