# Specifying enum size in C++0x

Tags: c++, c++03

I have a doubt regarding non-scoped enums behavior in `C++03`. I have read multiple questions and articles on Stack overflow and other pages.

I am using `C++0x` standard and running on `GCC 4.6.4`

I am able to define the non-scoped enum with a size(like *int*). refer [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/afzvvh)

```
#include<iostream>

enum Enum: int;
enum Enum: int
{
    first,
    second,
    third
};
 
int main()
{
    int numbers = first;
    switch (numbers)
    {
        case first: break;
        case second: break;
        default: break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't specifying the size of enum is `C++11` feature?

I found an answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853368/underlying-type-of-a-c-enum-in-c0x) claiming that we can define scoped enums with size if we declare them before defining. That answer provided [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations) link. But wiki link has been updated for `C++11` and referece of `C++03` has been removed.

So can we define or not the size of `enum` in `C++03`? Is the code(pasted above)is a valid `C++03` code? If we can define then does it impact the underlying type of `enum`?

Comment: If you use C++0x, you are enabling whatever C++11 features GCC was able to implement up to that point. That was the purpose of C++0x (when it was still believed that C++11 will be complete before 2010).

Comment: C++11 was meant to be a bit earlier than 11, thats why the compiler option is called `C++0x` before it was finalized

Comment: Thanks for comments. Its clear now that the `C++0x` is based on draft versions of `C++`. `C++11` after committee made it a standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't specifying the size of enum is C++11 feature?

You seem to refer to specifying the underlying type. Yes, it was introduced in C++11.

> So can we define or not the size of enum in C++03?

No, we cannot.

> Is the code(pasted above)is a valid C++03 code?

No, it isn't.

> I am using C++0x standard

C++0x was the name of C++11 while it was being worked on. At the time the name was chosen, they probably hoped to publish it prior to 2010.

Thus, if you use "C++0x", then you are using an experimental implementation of a C++11 standard draft and thus this feature may be available. Note that newer GCC which fully support C++11 still accept `-std=c++0x` option in which case you would in fact be using the full and stable implementation of C++11. GCC 4.6.4 does not have full support though.

Similarly, C++1y is the working name of C++14, C++2a corresponds to C++20 and C++2b corresponds to C++23 (hopefully).

Comment: C++0x is not necessarily an experimental implementation. The latest version of gcc still accepts it and afaik its just a synonym for C++11

Comment: actually as you wrote it is it not wrong, but maybe misleading. I am talking about the flag, when you say "if you use "C++0x".." you refer to the implementation I suppose

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that for *non-scoped* enums, both pre C++11 and post, what you can do is [wrap the enum in a Typesafe Idiom idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Safe_Enum) in order to specify the size you want.

(Take into consideration: once you do this the wrapped type is a `class` type, not an `enum` or scalar type)

Alternatively, for GCC specifically you can add a value to the enum that has the value of the largest valid value for the size you want (so eg.: `(uint64_t)-1` for a 64-bit enumeration) / the largest negative value, then enable the `--fshort-enums` flag, which will ensure that the enum has the type of the smallest integral that fits your values. In your example,  you'd need something like:

```
enum Enum
{
    first,
    second,
    third,
    _dummy = INT_MIN
};
```

Don't quote me but this *should* be portable across all versions of the Standard where the compiler implements `-fshort-enums` or an equivalent compiler flag, meaning you can use this code pre- and post- C++11.

Comment: Wrt the "should be portable", the `-fshort-enum` option forces GCC to make a choice which is legal in any C++ standard. And the `INT_MIN` ensures that this choice is `int`, again regardless of C++ standard.